# Auto-refresh page every minute?

Tags: headers

How do I make a WP page (w/ dynamic content) auto-refresh every minute?

With PHP, I'd use a "Refresh:" header, and in HTML I could use a 
HTTP-EQUIV tag or something.

However, WP generates headers itself, and I can't tweak anything until 
the body, no?

I searched in vain for a plug-in that does this.

Comment: Why not use javascript?

Answer (score 2):

you can add `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">` to your header.php file in wordpress theme.

**EDIT:** I removed the last bit of code and just made a plugin with read me file and the functions you would want.

You can download the plugin from here [WP Auto Refresh Plugin](http://c211715.r15.cf1.rackcdn.com/auto_refresh.zip) and install it from the beck-end. Note i did not create a graphical UI so the plugin will need to be modified from the file it self. Maybe ill develop a basic UI but for now i need to work on some other higher priority projects. the plugin can be found in your /wp-content/plugins directory under auto_refresh.

Comment: just a side note i did try the plugin code and it works. Nice thing with this is it can be a plugin instead of a theme edit so no worries on updates and if you want to disable just disable it

Comment: OK, I did this and it worked (despite spewing out an error when I activated the plugin). How do I limit it to specific pages? I don't need them all refreshing every minute. Can I create "header-slug" pages, or does that only work for page-slug and post-slug?

Comment: are you wanting certain pages or certain posts?

Comment: Can you tell me what error it spit out at yeah

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to a plugin that should do what your looking for

Comment: did you remove the plugin? i was searching for such a plugin for a long time... :-(

Comment: not that i know of ill check later.